# How to generate a random signal in multisim 14.1

Tags: adc, simulation, multisim, human-signal

I'm trying to design a circuit which digitised a very noisy input. It is normally +/- 1mv but will randomly peak up to +/- 20mv, the frequency of interest is 0.1<hz<10 but the signal contains higher frequency components up to 40 Hz. In order to best design the circuit I want to create a rudimentary model of the signal in multisim.

I know you can simulate thermal noise but does anyone know if there's a way to simulate other types of noise?